# Having trouble making one JQuery variable depend on another

Tags: jquery, variables

I have a variable called `IndependentVar1random` that has 2 possible values (A or B). If the `IndependentVar1random` is "A", I want `DependentVar1random` to equal either 'a' or 'aa'.  (If `IndependentVar1random` is "B", I don't want `DependentVar1random' to equal anything.)

I tried the following code (and many other iterations), but I can't get this to work:   https://jsfiddle.net/ta3og5g3/23/

(I added a comment with asterisks at the problematic portion of the code...there's an issue with the "if" statement that I can't identify. I'm not sure if a function can be nested within another function in the way that I have done so.)

HTML

```
<span class="IndependentVar1randomreplacer">  ///This is what gets replaced by the value of IndependentVar1random
</span>

<span class="DependentVar1randomreplacer"> ///This is what gets replaced by the value of DependentVar1random
</span>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
  function IndependentVarselector1() {
  var IndependentVar1= ['A', 'B'];
    var IndependentVar1random = IndependentVar1[Math.floor(Math.random() * IndependentVar1.length)];
    return IndependentVar1random;  ///EVERYTHING UP UNTIL THIS POINT SUCCESSFULLY GENERATES INDEPENDENTVAR1RANDOM

       if ( IndependentVar1random == A) {  ///**PROBLEM AREA*** THIS DOES NOT GENERATE DEPENDENTVAR1 BASED ON THE INDEPENDENTVAR1RANDOM

                function DependentVarselector1() {
  var DependentVar1= ['a', 'aa'];
    var DependentVar1random = DependentVar1[Math.floor(Math.random() * DependentVar1.length)];
    return DependentVar1random;
}    
}
}

///THE CODE BELOW (SUCCESSFULLY) REPLACES THE SPANS WITH THE VALUES OF THE VARIALBES; NO ISSUE HERE

var IndependentVar1randomreplacer = IndependentVarselector1();  
 $('.IndependentVar1randomreplacer').html(IndependentVar1randomreplacer );

 var DependentVar1randomreplacer = DependentVarselector1();
 $('.DependentVar1randomreplacer').html(DependentVar1randomreplacer );

 });
```

Comment: `function DependentVarselector1()` will never be available for use unless `IndependentVar1random=='A'`, move that out as it's own function under `$(document).ready(...)`

Comment: @Napoli Thank you for your reply! I tried doing that, but it didn't help. Here's my attempt: https://jsfiddle.net/ta3og5g3/29/

Comment: If you open your console on that fiddle you'll notice that it is complaining because that one function is declared in an if, meaning there are cases where it will not be defined and if you try to reference it in that case that is an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a lot wrong with the code above, below is a simplified version:

```
function IndependentVarselector1() {
    var IndependentVar1= ['A', 'B'];
    var IndependentVar1random = IndependentVar1[Math.floor(Math.random() * IndependentVar1.length)];
    return IndependentVar1random;
}

function DependentVarselector1(var1) {
    if ( var1 == 'A')
        return null;

    var DependentVar1= ['a', 'aa'];
    var DependentVar1random = DependentVar1[Math.floor(Math.random() * DependentVar1.length)];
    return DependentVar1random;
}

$(document).ready(function () {    
    var IndependentVar1randomreplacer = IndependentVarselector1();  
    $('.IndependentVar1randomreplacer').html(IndependentVar1randomreplacer );

    var DependentVar1randomreplacer = DependentVarselector1(  IndependentVar1randomreplacer );
    $('.DependentVar1randomreplacer').html(DependentVar1randomreplacer );
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the help! I just modified the code slightly so that it doesn't use `return null` as that seems to set `DependentVar` only if the first variable is NOT equal to A.  Modified form: https://jsfiddle.net/ta3og5g3/44/

Answer (score 0):

```
 if ( IndependentVar1random == A) {
```

Should be

```
 if ( IndependentVar1random == 'A') {
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply :) I tried that already, but it didn't do the trick, unfortunately...